# SQL syntax error when using DATE_ADD()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

so I am trying to return all appointments more than 24 hours ahead of time.  I'm positive the error in the code is around the DATE_ADD stuff, so I know that the PHP variables are set correctly.  I think I am just thinking about DATE_ADD wrong.  I have also tried several variations of brackets with no luck. Just CURDATE() works.   Thanks for any help!

```
$sql =  "   SELECT DISTINCT timeBlocks.date
            FROM timeBlocks
            WHERE timeBlocks.location = '".$appointmentLocation."' AND timeBlocks.school = '".$_SESSION["school"]."' AND timeBlocks.date >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
            ORDER BY timeBlocks.date ASC;";
```

Comment: My experience taught me that using the **[HEREDOC](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)** syntax for multiline strings is better.

Comment: Thanks!  I will read through this now.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2553439 << example usage with your query.

Comment: thanks for adding that for me, it really helped me to understand how to write it out correctly!

Comment: Also. Please don't change the original meaning of the questions, if by any chance a different person would google search your problem, he won't be able to find it if you changed it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is too obvious, but it says `INTERVAL 1 YEAR` instead of 24 hours.

Comment: wow, that totally worked, i feel like a FOOL, thanks so much for finding that...I can't accept the answer for 5 more mins.  I realized that there are no appointments for next year yet, so the empty set was causing the syntax error, i think.

Comment: Haha we all have moments like this. I once spent 4 hours trying to solve an error that was solved by removing a single quotation mark. Glad to help!

Comment: When having moments like these, it usually means you should've hit the bed around 2 hours ago.